# Geoserver crashing permgen space error

Tags: geoserver, osx

I am running **geoserver 2.8.1** on **Mac OS X 10.10**. I have installed geoserver with homebrew. I have no idea why geoserver is crashing but I get this error below when I try preview a layer, create a layer or just about anything. This happens after a few clicks on different menus. Can not see any pattern here. What happens on the OS X machine is it is running 2 JAVA programs. If I am able to kill both, I restart geoserver and only 1 JAVA program is running. Here is a typical output. Does anyone have an idea as to where I can start to debug?

> HTTP ERROR: 500

PermGen space
RequestURI=/geoserver/web/

Caused by:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space     at
>   org.geoserver.web.GeoServerApplication$RequestCycle.onRuntimeException(GeoServerApplication.java:311)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.onRuntimeException(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:223)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.respond(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:120)
>     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1379)  at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)  at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)     at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:138)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:159)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)

Powered by Jetty://

**UPDATE**
When I increase the memory I now get this error:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onFormSubmitted of interface org.    apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at component [    MarkupContainer [Component id = resource]] threw an exception
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.    java:193)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.    ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.processEvents(ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.    java:73)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(    AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doPost(WicketServlet.java:160)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.    handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:159)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(    AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(    SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet    .java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.    java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(    FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.    java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.    java:1093)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(    ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.    java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(    SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(    SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.    java:46)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.    java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.    java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.    java:1084)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(    FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.    doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.    invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.    doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.    doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(    GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(    FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.    doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(    ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.    doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(    GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(    FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(    GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(    FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.    doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.    AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(    AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.    doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(    GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.    doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(    FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.    doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.    RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.    doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(    GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(    FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.    doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.    doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.    doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.    doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(    GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(    FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.    java:173)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(    GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(    DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(    DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.    java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.    java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.    java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.    java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.    java:1084)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(    CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(    OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.    java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(    ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.    java:842)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:648)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:205)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.    java:450)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor225.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.    java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.    java:182)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter message can't be null
    at org.apache.wicket.feedback.FeedbackMessage.<init>(FeedbackMessage.java:102)
    at org.apache.wicket.feedback.FeedbackMessages.error(FeedbackMessages.java:135)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.error(Component.java:1309)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.resource.ResourceConfigurationPage.doSave(    ResourceConfigurationPage.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.resource.ResourceConfigurationPage$6.onSubmit(    ResourceConfigurationPage.java:258)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1561)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:958)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:920)
    ... 97 more
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with osx and homebrew, but this error typically happens because the JVM is not given enough permgen, you should give it at least 128MB:
http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/production/container.html

Comment: I found a setting in **/usr/local/Cellar/geoserver/2.8.1/libexec/bin/startup.sh**  and changed this to: `export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=4000m"`but that did not help. Geoserver is still crashing. I do not get the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen` but I get another error, very long. See it above.

Comment: Solved my problems by uninstalling the BREW version of geoserver and running the "Platform Independent Binary" version from geoserver.org. Have not had problems since. Seems the BREW version of geoserver is fishy and not well supported.